# Split XML file based on string

Tags: xml, bash, split

i've mixed up some xml files and now have something like

```
<Schema>
stuff
</Schema><Schema>
stuff
</Schema><Schema>
..
```

i need to split them all so to have from `<Schema>` to `</Schema>` in each file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). It splits registers with end tag and if there are characters before it print all it:

```
awk -c '
    BEGIN { RS = "</Schema>" } 
    $0 ~ /[^[:blank:]\n]/ { 
        printf "%s\n", $0 RS >> FILENAME "_" ++i ".xml" 
    }
' infile
```

Assuming `infile` with content:

```
<Schema>
stuff
</Schema><Schema>
more stuff
</Schema><Schema>
and more stuff
</Schema>
```

It yields:

```
==> infile_1.xml <==
<Schema>
stuff
</Schema>

==> infile_2.xml <==
<Schema>
more stuff
</Schema>

==> infile_3.xml <==
<Schema>
and more stuff
</Schema>
```

Comment: amazing. one cool thing would be to have the output like this "infile_1.xml" "infile_2.xml" and so on

Comment: @mfirry: Simply add `FILENAME` variable to the output redirection of the `printf`. I've updated the answer with it.

Comment: awesome! one more thing before declaring you my saviour is i'm gonna have to put it in a sh file and inside a 'for file in .' kinda thing. it'll hopefully work, right?

Comment: @mfirry: Why should not work? I can't see much problem. That is not a problem of `awk`.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
for file in $(find . "*.xml")
do
  awk -c '
        BEGIN { RS = "</Schema>" } 
        $0 ~ /[^[:blank:]\n]/ { 
                printf "%s\n", $0 RS >> FILENAME "_" ++i
        }
        ' $file
done

with that i get some gawk error
Usage: gawk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...

Comment: @mfirry: It works for me. Try to remove `-c` switch, that is useless for this case and look for the error in your favourite  search engine.